# How do I sort in ascending/descending order this poorly parsed JSON data returned by tweepy in Python?

Tags: python, json, sorting, tweepy

I'm trying to build myself a program that returns the top two trending topics with tweet amounts send from the given location on twitter. Which I can do through their API but I'm having trouble working with the JSON data return by the API. I am new to the coding scene and I google most of my stuff. I really don't know if there is an easier way to pull info from a JSON data, I googled quite a bit but I failed to handle it.

I whipped up the code below and I'm able to print out the hashtag and the tweet amount but I don't know how I can sort them out in a descending order. Can anyone help me? I tried the sorted function but it only sorts the tweet amount in itself so if 54958 tweets were sent it sorts it into 45589. I failed to compare each tweets sent with themselves.

I failed to detail my question last time and I was blocked two days from asking questions so if I make any mistakes here again please bare with me, thanks!

```
import tweepy
import json
import time
from private import consumer_key,consumer_secret


def hashtag():
    auth = tweepy.AppAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    hashtag = api.trends_place(23424969)
    h_json = json.dumps(hashtag)
    h_dict = json.loads(h_json)
    h_trends = h_dict[0]
    h_trends2 = h_trends['trends']
    h_sondict = h_trends2[0:]
    for tweet in (h_sondict):
        i =+ 1
        a = '{}'.format(tweet['name'])
        b = '{}'.format(tweet['tweet_volume'])
        c = []
        c.append(a)
        c = c[0]
        d = []
        d.append(b)
        print(c,d)

hashtag()
```

Which returns this;

```
#SahipsizElazığ ['10822']
#iyikidoğdunSefaReis ['None']
#MenajerimiAra ['None']
#ileri3lü ['None']
#BuGeceSirenlerSaat21 ['32657']
selahattin demirtaş ['None']
Etİtlafına FurkanBahanesi ['None']
KHKZulmü YeterArtık ['34557']
Hasic ['None']
Sergen ['None']
Türkçeyi ['None']
Çağatay Ulusoy ['None']
Prof. Dr. Arif Ersoy ['None']
AhlaksızOyun Bozuldu ['None']
Nsakala ['None']
TEKDER32 Yaşında ['None']
Rıdvan ['None']
SMAlılara BağışYap ['21992']
Welinton ['None']
Mensah ['None']
Rehabilitasyona Sahipçık ['None']
AYMSiyasiDeğil BağımsızKarar ['21637']
Yasin Börü ['None']
Osmanlıca ['None']
Johansen ['None']
ÖğrtmnMüjde Bekliyor ['76120']
Necip ['None']
Lens ['39612']
Zeki Yavru ['None']
#masterchefturkiye ['11174']
#umutaksututuklansın ['15529']
#UzaktanEğitim ['None']
#Şereftir2Eylül ['None']
#reisleşahlanmayadevam ['19021']
#TekeTek ['12866']
#DüşYakamızdanParaAvcısı ['None']
#HekimoğluYeniSezon ['None']
#27Kadın ['16998']
#SiyahKuğu ['None']
#CnnTürkMasası ['None']
#ilaydayasesol ['None']
#DünyaGümüşhanelilerGünü ['None']
#AyşeKocaBabasınıGörmeli ['29864']
#ReisBizimSoyluBizim ['None']
#Eylulgeldi ['None']
#yunuscansuveoğlubulunsun ['13074']
#ZiyaNolduk ['99630']
#BJKvSİV ['None']
#nevükararınıaçıkla ['None']
#eskisehirhibritistiyor ['10720']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful initializing a new list in the for loop, it's not saving the variables you're using to be used on the outside. I'm not sure what you want to do with `c` and `d` lists, but you need to declare them outside your for loop.

To sort the data, assuming you have a list you can do something like this:
`sorted([('a', 1),('b', 3),('d', 4), ('x',12)], key=lambda x: x[1])`
which will sort the values in ascending order.

I'll let you figure out the implementation of how to do that.

Comment: I'll fiddle around and see what I can do. When I declare them outside my loop it prints out only 1 line. As I've said, I'll just fiddle around the code and see for myself haha, thanks!